# Android: Can the same certificate be used for debug and release

Tags: android, certificate, signing

Is it possible to use the same certificate for signing an app in debug and release? Why does there even have to be two separate certificates?

Comment: As far as I understand: No because Eclipse (if you are using it) is signing debug certs, while you have to get a real one, if you wanna publish the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Debug certificate* is used during development.

*Release certificate* is used when you need to distribute your app via Google Play.

If you don't want to distribute your app via Google, then perhaps you may stick to debug certificate. Note that debug shows/handle more of the logging stuff and makes your app run a little slower because of this.

Comment: So you're saying it is impossible to just use one certificate for both?

Comment: For more info, read this http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html